# Change html title with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hey so I have about 10 php pages with different titles coded like this :

```
< title >some title here< /title>
```

I'm using jquery's `$('title').html('new title')` to dynamically change the title but this changes the title for all the php pages. Is there a way to specify the page whose title I want to change.
I'm using one .js script for the ten pages so any code which references document would affect all the 10 php pages. I want to only affect say thisone.php

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just generate the right HTML from the start - with PHP?

Comment: because the title changes periodically.

Comment: I don't follow, and I don't think I'm the only one confused about what you're asking. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: I gather the following: He's got one giant .js file that does everything. Only some of the PHP files need to have the title changed periodically. However, since he is including the same giant .js file in all of the files, the title changes in all of them. The solution, clearly, should be to make a different .js file for title changing and include it only in the PHP files that need changing titles.

Comment: exactly. I was hoping there was  another solution where I dont have create another .js page to handle title changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hope this help

var url =document.URL
var title=''
switch (url)
{
case "abc.com/1.php":
  title="title1";
  break;
case "abc.com/2.php":
  title="title2";
  break;
default:
  title="titledefault";
}
document.title = title;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple.

```
document.title="YOUR TITLE HERE";
```

Put that in your jQuery function.

EDIT: OP's question updated.

If your title changes periodically, but only on some PHP files, only include the code to change the title on those PHP files.

Comment: No this would change all the php pages title because they all share one .js external page

Comment: Oh, you edited your question from its original form. I'm confused what you're asking. Can't you just set the title in PHP then? Could you provide more context? I'm having trouble seeing what the problem is.

Comment: I can't do that because they all share one .js file

Comment: Then make a new .js file for changing the title.

Comment: I could do that but I'm pretty sure there is a way to reference the php page and that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: Making a separate .js file is a better and easier solution.

Comment: So if i have 30 different pages I would be making 30 .js scripts. I don't think that is an efficient way.

Comment: No, you would make one additional .js script to change the title to whatever you want and include that one .js file only in the PHP files that you want to have dynamic titles on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribut to the html generated by PHP like `<html title='Your title'>`

the you code would look like that :

```
    document.title = $('html')attr('title');
```

Comment: I want to set the title dynamically.

Comment: I don't know if you saw, but i edited my old "non-dynamic" title. Now it is dynamic

Comment: Yes, but once again this would set the title of all the 10 pages since they would are sharing an external .js page

Comment: Ahah well now i'm lost! I think we need some examples.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   document.title = "Hello World!";

});
```

Comment: This would work but is not what i'm looking for. I'm using a shared external .js script so all php pages which use that script would have the titles changed since i'm using document.title